# Invertible modules of the free group on the isomorphism classes of projective modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $G$ be the free group on the isomorphism classes of (finitely generated) projective $R$-modules. If $P$ is a projective $R$-module, then $[P]$ denotes the isomorphism class of projective modules of $P$. Define the addition in $G$ by $[P]+[Q]=[P\bigoplus Q]$.

We know that $[P]=[Q]$ iff $P\bigoplus R^n\cong Q\bigoplus R^n$ for some integer $n$. I want to show that if $P$ and $Q$ are invertible modules and $[P]=[Q]$, then $P\cong Q$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean “$G$ is the free abelian group on the isomorphism classes of finitely generated projective $R$-modules”? Show that (eg) $P \cong \Lambda^{n+1}(P \oplus R^n)$.

Comment: @Mindlack Is is true that isomorphism? Are the exterior powers of P all zero from 2 on? Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, I should have stated that $P$ was assumed to be an invertible module.

Comment: @Mindlack How could we know exterior powers of invertible modules vanish when 
 $\geq 2$ ? It may be generated by more than one element as an $R$-module, if $R$ isn't local.

Comment: Because their localizations are free of rank one so their exterior power of degree $\geq 2$ vanishes. Thus the localization at any prime of the exterior power of $P$ of degree at least $2$ is zero. QED

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right